# RSS publish dates - should that be in English?

Tags: c#, xml

I create RSS items. I've a column called date_published, which is DateTime column in MS SQL database.  e.g. it contains "2011-05-04 15:19:05.630"

Below is the C# code date I re-generate RSS acceptable date format  (input database field).

Input:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(item.date_published).ToString("r")
```

Output:

```
Wed, 04 May 2011 15:19:05 GMT
```

So I looked with Notepad in the XML file and the result look above.

**Problem:**

When the users receive this item in Outlook RSS feedreader, it displays +2 hours ahead. So it displays in email outlook received date  2011-05-04 17:19:05

So I change my code from:

```
item.pubdate_published.Value.ToString("r")
```

To:

```
item.pubdate_published.Value.ToString("ddd dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +2 G'M'T")
```

This gives me exact what I want like this : mer, 04 mai 2011 15:19:05 +2 GMT.

PROBLEM:
My RSS XMl file shows like that too (above), but my OUTLOOK email received date is 06/January/2011 09:32

So the only issue I can think is the language problem... Because the dates are generated in Dutch or French.

if this is the issue: How do I write the dates in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem... the datetime in RSS XML file must be in English. So we were generating the date sometimes Dutch and sometimes in French.

this is what I did:
item.pubdate_published.Value.ToString("r").replace("GMT",("+2 GMT");

the hours and the dates are correct now.

be careful doing like this : ToString("ddd dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +2 G'M'T") will generate specific language and not always English. ("r") always generate in English.